# Recreating nested frequency tables fast

Tags: r

I find myself recreating nested frequency tables over and over again from articles using matrix and recreating tables (or sometimes giving up and using `rep` and making the full data set which is very time consuming.  I'm looking for the fastest way (least code) to recreate this nested frequency table in R (I assume this is a question that many can benefit from).

```
              gender female male
hs.grad race                    
no      asian             3    4
        black             5   10
        white            17   11
yes     asian             5    7
        black             1    9
        white            11   17
```

This was created using `ftable` if that's helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
file = tempfile()
cat (text='              gender female male
hs.grad race                    
no      asian             3    4
        black             5   10
        white            17   11
yes     asian             5    7
        black             1    9
        white            11   17
', file=file)
ft = read.ftable(file)
```

Or

```
> read.ftable(textConnection("              gender female male
+ hs.grad race                    
+ no      asian             3    4
+         black             5   10
+         white            17   11
+ yes     asian             5    7
+         black             1    9
+         white            11   17"))
```

Comment: I knew about the text argument to read.table but never thought to use it with read.ftable +1 and the check.